# Jquery 2 Clicks function Animate

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I would like to make a div slide to the right on its first click and when its clicked again, I'd like it to return to the original position

I have the following but the div doesnt move and console.log shows clicked-2 even on the first click.

```
$('.note-title').click(function(){
        console.log("clicked-1");
        $(this).animate({'margin-left':'200px'},200);
    },function(){
        console.log("clicked-2");
        $(this).animate({'margin-left':'0px'},200);
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

What about simply using a boolean flag?

```
var clickOne = true;
$('.note-title').click(function(){
  if (clickOne){
    $(this).animate({'margin-left':'200px'},200);
  }else{
    $(this).animate({'margin-left':'0px'},200);
  }
  clickOne = !clickOne;
}
```

Each click toggles the value of the flag and executes a different part of the conditional expression.

Answer (score 1):

**Note** This method is [depreciated](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11786). You should use Lix's solution.

---

Use [`.toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)

```
$('.note-title').toggle(function(){
    console.log("clicked-1");
    $(this).animate({'margin-left':'200px'},200);
},function(){
    console.log("clicked-2");
    $(this).animate({'margin-left':'0px'},200);
});
```

With `.click`, all passed in callbacks will get triggered with each click, one after the other.

Comment: `toggle` mouse event is _deprecated_.

Comment: @undefined Ah, I missed that in the change log. It isn't changed in the api yet. http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11786

Comment: @KevinB The only places that deprecation of `toggle` has been mentioned are on the breadcrumb _Categories: Deprecated | Events > Mouse Events_ and [`deprecated`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/) page, it's a bit confusing, unfortunately.

Comment: It's also in the blog post. There's quite a few cases within the api that haven't been updated for the 1.8.0 release.